# Show confirmation box on exit(hardware button) in phonegap app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am working on a iframe android app on phonegap. I use phonegap build to compile my code online. For a day,I am searching for a code that pop out confirmation box that shows "do you want to exit?" yes|no ?? I comeout with these code.But it is not working.Can you help out? do we have to add any plugin in config.xml?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Test Layout</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false); //Listen to the User clicking on the back button
}
function onBackKeyDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    navigator.notification.confirm("Are you sure you want to exit ?", onConfirm, "Confirmation", "Yes,No"); 
    // Prompt the user with the choice
}
function onConfirm(button) {
    if(button==2){//If User selected No, then we just do nothing
        return;
    }else{
        navigator.app.exitApp();// Otherwise we quit the app.
    }
}
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            body, html
            {
                margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;
            }
            #content
            {
                position:absolute; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; top: 0px; 
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="#" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Apache Cordova / Phonegap you don't need any plug-in for the native events (like `deviceready` or`backbutton`) but you need the `cordova-plugin-dialogs` [plug-in](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-dialogs/index.html) to show the native alerts.

So, I'm guessing that your problem is not to catch the event, but to show the alert.

Please, try just ti print a classic `window.alert()`, to verify if the event is catch, after that you can try with the dialog plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

I think two changes are there in your code

first, if you haven't added `cordova.js` then please add it to your header section of file

second, before calling backbutton event you need to give some time to complete loading of the page otherwise it will not understand the back button click event

So here I just added timeout to your function

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false); //Listen to the User clicking on the back button
    },500);
}
```

Here is my working code too.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.addEventListener('backbutton', function(e){    
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to exit app?"))
            {
                navigator.app.exitApp();
            }   
        }, false);
    }, 500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my working code on pressing backbutton it will ask for exit

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    navigator.notification.confirm("Are you sure want to exit from App?", onConfirmExit, "Confirmation", "Yes,No");
}, false);


function onConfirmExit(button) {
    if (button == 2) { //If User select a No, then return back;
        return;
    } else {
        navigator.app.exitApp(); // If user select a Yes, quit from the app.
    }
}
```